# Web service actionscript error

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, web-services, flex3

I am new to Flex and needed some help setting up Web service client.

I have a web service of method:

```
 public String printEchoStr(String str);
```

I am facing problem while creating action script to call this service. I am getting error:

```
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type
 generated.webservices:PrintEcho.
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way.

Thanks,

-H

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute"
    xmlns:srv="generated.webservices.*"
    creationComplete="initFunc()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import generated.webservices.EchoService;
            import generated.webservices.PrintEchoStrResultEvent;
            import generated.webservices.PrintEchoResultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import generated.webservices.PrintEchoStr;
            import generated.webservices.PrintEcho;

            public var myService:EchoService = new EchoService();

            private function initFunc():void{
                myService.addprintEchoStrEventListener(argPrintEchoStr);
/*--------------
 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type String to an unrelated type 
 generated.webservices:PrintEcho. at line below
----------------*/
                myService.printEchoStr(textAreaPrintEchoStr.text); 
                myService.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT,myServices_faultHandler);
            }

            public function argPrintEchoStr(event:PrintEchoStrResultEvent):void{
                trace(event.result);
            }

            private function myServices_faultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void {
                Alert.show(event.fault.faultString,"error with WebServices");
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:TextArea id ="textAreaPrintEchoStr" 
        x="81" y="125"/>

</mx:Application>
```

Generated source of EchoService.as
**EchoService.as**

```
    package generated.webservices
{
    import mx.rpc.AsyncToken;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
    import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import mx.rpc.soap.types.*;

    /**
     * Dispatches when a call to the operation printEcho completes with success
     * and returns some data
     * @eventType PrintEchoResultEvent
     */
    [Event(name="PrintEcho_result", type="generated.webservices.PrintEchoResultEvent")]

    /**
     * Dispatches when a call to the operation printEchoStr completes with success
     * and returns some data
     * @eventType PrintEchoStrResultEvent
     */
    [Event(name="PrintEchoStr_result", type="generated.webservices.PrintEchoStrResultEvent")]

    /**
     * Dispatches when the operation that has been called fails. The fault event is common for all operations
     * of the WSDL
     * @eventType mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent
     */
    [Event(name="fault", type="mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent")]

    public class EchoService extends EventDispatcher implements IEchoService
    {
        private var _baseService:BaseEchoService;

        /**
         * Constructor for the facade; sets the destination and create a baseService instance
         * @param The LCDS destination (if any) associated with the imported WSDL
         */  
        public function EchoService(destination:String=null,rootURL:String=null)
        {
            _baseService = new BaseEchoService(destination,rootURL);
        }

        //stub functions for the printEcho operation


        /**
         * @see IEchoService#printEcho()
         */
        public function printEcho(printEcho:PrintEcho):AsyncToken
        {
            var _internal_token:AsyncToken = _baseService.printEcho(printEcho);
            _internal_token.addEventListener("result",_printEcho_populate_results);
            _internal_token.addEventListener("fault",throwFault); 
            return _internal_token;
        }
        /**
         * @see IEchoService#printEcho_send()
         */    
        public function printEcho_send():AsyncToken
        {
            return printEcho(_printEcho_request.printEcho);
        }

        /**
         * Internal representation of the request wrapper for the operation
         * @private
         */
        private var _printEcho_request:PrintEcho_request;
        /**
         * @see IEchoService#printEcho_request_var
         */
        [Bindable]
        public function get printEcho_request_var():PrintEcho_request
        {
            return _printEcho_request;
        }

        /**
         * @private
         */
        public function set printEcho_request_var(request:PrintEcho_request):void
        {
            _printEcho_request = request;
        }

            /**
         * Internal variable to store the operation's lastResult
         * @private
         */
        private var _printEcho_lastResult:PrintEchoResponse;
        [Bindable]
        /**
         * @see IEchoService#printEcho_lastResult
         */   
        public function get printEcho_lastResult():PrintEchoResponse
        {
            return _printEcho_lastResult;
        }
        /**
         * @private
         */
        public function set printEcho_lastResult(lastResult:PrintEchoResponse):void
        {
            _printEcho_lastResult = lastResult;
        }

        /**
         * @see IEchoService#addprintEcho()
         */
        public function addprintEchoEventListener(listener:Function):void
        {
            addEventListener(PrintEchoResultEvent.PrintEcho_RESULT,listener);
        }

        /**
         * @private
         */
        private function _printEcho_populate_results(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            var e:PrintEchoResultEvent = new PrintEchoResultEvent();
                    e.result = event.result as PrintEchoResponse;
                               e.headers = event.headers;
                     printEcho_lastResult = e.result;
                     dispatchEvent(e);
                    }

        //stub functions for the printEchoStr operation


        /**
         * @see IEchoService#printEchoStr()
         */
        public function printEchoStr(printEchoStr:PrintEchoStr):AsyncToken
        {
            var _internal_token:AsyncToken = _baseService.printEchoStr(printEchoStr);
            _internal_token.addEventListener("result",_printEchoStr_populate_results);
            _internal_token.addEventListener("fault",throwFault); 
            return _internal_token;
        }
        /**
         * @see IEchoService#printEchoStr_send()
         */    
        public function printEchoStr_send():AsyncToken
        {
            return printEchoStr(_printEchoStr_request.printEchoStr);
        }

        /**
         * Internal representation of the request wrapper for the operation
         * @private
         */
        private var _printEchoStr_request:PrintEchoStr_request;
        /**
         * @see IEchoService#printEchoStr_request_var
         */
        [Bindable]
        public function get printEchoStr_request_var():PrintEchoStr_request
        {
            return _printEchoStr_request;
        }

        /**
         * @private
         */
        public function set printEchoStr_request_var(request:PrintEchoStr_request):void
        {
            _printEchoStr_request = request;
        }

            /**
         * Internal variable to store the operation's lastResult
         * @private
         */
        private var _printEchoStr_lastResult:PrintEchoStrResponse;
        [Bindable]
        /**
         * @see IEchoService#printEchoStr_lastResult
         */   
        public function get printEchoStr_lastResult():PrintEchoStrResponse
        {
            return _printEchoStr_lastResult;
        }
        /**
         * @private
         */
        public function set printEchoStr_lastResult(lastResult:PrintEchoStrResponse):void
        {
            _printEchoStr_lastResult = lastResult;
        }

        /**
         * @see IEchoService#addprintEchoStr()
         */
        public function addprintEchoStrEventListener(listener:Function):void
        {
            addEventListener(PrintEchoStrResultEvent.PrintEchoStr_RESULT,listener);
        }

        /**
         * @private
         */
        private function _printEchoStr_populate_results(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            var e:PrintEchoStrResultEvent = new PrintEchoStrResultEvent();
                    e.result = event.result as PrintEchoStrResponse;
                               e.headers = event.headers;
                     printEchoStr_lastResult = e.result;
                     dispatchEvent(e);
                    }

        //service-wide functions
        /**
         * @see IEchoService#getWebService()
         */
        public function getWebService():BaseEchoService
        {
            return _baseService;
        }

        /**
         * Set the event listener for the fault event which can be triggered by each of the operations defined by the facade
         */
        public function addEchoServiceFaultEventListener(listener:Function):void
        {
            addEventListener("fault",listener);
        }

        /**
         * Internal function to re-dispatch the fault event passed on by the base service implementation
         * @private
         */

         private function throwFault(event:FaultEvent):void
         {
            dispatchEvent(event);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you upload the generated source for EchoService.as?

Comment: I have uploaded the code of EchoService generated by Data->Import WebService

Comment: I am trying to send a parameter print the response of the webservice in the TextArea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myService.printEchoStr(textAreaPrintEchoStr.text);
```

`printEchoStr` method of `EchoService` class expects a `PrintEcho` object, but you're passing `textAreaPrintEchoStr.text`, which is a `String`